# Find if there are three consecutive indices in a list that ARE NOT equal to zero in python

Tags: python, list

I am python beginner, so I thought I could solicit some help here.

Here are two input lists with only 0 and 1 for the sake of simplicity:

```
 x = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
 y = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

I am trying to define a logic in python that returns True for x because
it HAS three consecutive elements that ARE NOT EQUAL to zero; indices 0:2 are all not equal to zero.
The same function would return nothing for y because y DOES NOT have three consecutive elements that ARE NOT EQUAL to zero. I also mean consecutive in regards to the indices, not in regards to the values!

In addition to solving this logic, the function should also return the index and the value of the last non-zero element of a patch of 3 non-zero elements in case the original condition is true.

so, let's say I have a hypothetical function called is_three_consecutive_non_zero, here is what the function would return in either case:

```
is_three_consecutive_non_zero(x) # should evaluates to (True, 2, 1)
```

2 is the index of the last 1 in group of three consecutive ones and 1 is the value of the last non-zero element of the patch of non-zero three elements!

If the first output is false, the function doesn't return anything else.

Here is an annoying trio nested for-loop function with several if conditions that can be a good starting point:

```
def is_three_consecutive_non_zero(list):
if 0 not in list:
    return True, len(list)-1, list[len(list)-1]

for l in range(0, len(list)):
    for m in range(1, len(list)):
        for n in range(2, len(list)):
            if (l != m) & (m != l) & (n == m + 1) & (m == l + 1):
                if (list[l] != 0) & (list[m] != 0) & (list[n] != 0):
                    return True, n, list[n]
```

Let's try it:

```
is_three_consecutive_non_zero(x)
is_three_consecutive_non_zero(y)
```

It would be great if you could share any better logic or may be a single or two liner that utilize any other available python modules.
By the way, these list are very small, so, I am not concerned about time or space issues. I also only care about the FIRST PATCH of three non-zero elements:

```
z = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
is_three_consecutive_non_zero(z) # evaluates to (True, 3, 1) which is consistent with what I want
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Don't use names such as `list`, then you won't be able to do `list()` later on in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
def f(l):
    for i in range(len(l)-3):
        if all(l[i:i+3]):
            return True, i, l[i+2]
    return False, None, None
```

If you just want to get back whether or not three such values are in the list a one liner is `any(all(l[i:i+3]) for i in range(len(l)-3))`

Comment: Thanks Patrick, what if we can have values other than 0 and 1? How can we modify this accordingly?

Comment: I have reservations about using `all` for this, since it fails for all *falsy* objects not only 0

Comment: @mansanto The `all` and `any` functions rely on the fact that Python considers every object to have a truth value.  Get started [here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html)

Comment: Thanks Patrick, this function can be modified to deal with scenarios other than the 0, 1 scenario used above.

Comment: Considering OP is only concerned about 0 and 1 I think this is neat. I learn something new today.

Comment: Indexing, slicing windows and using `all` - brilliant python wielding.

Answer (score 2):

You could group your items using `itertools.groupby` and then check for the length of non-zero groups. Indices are added to the items in each group using `enumerate`:

```
from itertools import groupby

def is_three_consecutive_non_zero(lst):
  for k, g in groupby(enumerate(lst), lambda p: p[1]):
      g = list(g)
      # check that key is not 0 and group length is more than 2
      if k != 0 and len(g) > 2:
          return True, g[-1][0], k


x = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
y = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
print is_three_consecutive_non_zero(x)
# (True, 2, 1)

print is_three_consecutive_non_zero(y) # should probably return a 3-item tuple
# None
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, is_three_consecutive_non_zero([0, 1, 1, 1, 1]) evaluates to (True, 4, 1) instead of (True, 3, 1).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this version of the function. You can avoid most iterations.

```
def is_three_consecutive_non_zero(list):
  if 0 not in list:
      if len(list)>=3:
          return True, len(list)-1, list[len(list)-1]
  consecutiveNonZero=0
  for index,num in enumerate(list):
      if num is 0:
          consecutiveNonZero = 0
      else:
          consecutiveNonZero = consecutiveNonZero+1
      if consecutiveNonZero>=3:
          return True, index,num
  return False,-1,-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), we locate all indices and accept general windows of size `n` containing consecutive, non-zero values.

```
import more_itertools as mit


def is_consecutive(seq):
    """Return True if a sequence is consecutively increasing."""
    return tuple(seq) == tuple(range(seq[0], seq[-1]+1))

def consecutive_nonzero(lst, n=3):
    """Return True (bool, index, value) if windows are consecutively non-zero."""
    grouped_idxs = [w for w in mit.windowed(mit.locate(lst), n) if is_consecutive(w)]    # e.g. [(0, 1, 2)]
    return [(True, grp[-1], lst[grp[-1]]) for grp in grouped_idxs]

consecutive_nonzero([1, 1, 1, 0, 1])[0]
# (True, 2, 1)
```

Tests

```
import nose.tools as nt


def test_consecutive(f):
    """Verify results are consecutive and non-zero."""
    nt.eq_(f([1, 1, 0, 1, 0]), [])
    nt.eq_(f([1, 1, 1, 0, 1]), [(True, 2, 1)])
    nt.eq_(f([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]), [(True, 2, 1), (True, 6, 1)])
    nt.eq_(f([0, 1, 2, 3, 1]), [(True, 3, 3), (True, 4, 1)])
    nt.eq_(f([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0], n=5), [(True, 6, 1)])

test_consecutive(f=consecutive_nonzero)
```